# Conditional Probability Identity

Tags: probability

Let $X, Y, Z$ be random variables. Is it true that

$\sum_z P(X=x| Y=y , Z=z)P(Z=z) = P(X=x|Y=y)$ if and only if $Y$ and $Z$ are independent?

It can be easily shown using computation that if $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, the identity holds. I was wondering if the other direction holds.

Comment: Not quite, @JohnDoe.  See my answer.

Comment: @GrahamKemp oh ok thanks. I wasn't able to prove it, hence why I didn't put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the Law of Total Probability says that, for any $x$ and $y$, that: $$\begin{split}\mathsf P(X=x\mid Y=y) &=\sum_z \mathsf P(X=x, Z=z\mid Y=y)
\\ &=\sum_z \mathsf P(X=x\mid Y=y,Z=z)\mathsf P(Z=z\mid Y=y)
\end{split}$$

If $Y$ and $Z$ are independent we have $\forall y\forall z.\mathsf P(Z=z\mid Y=y)=\mathsf P(Z=z)$, by the very definition of independence.   So then do we have, for any $x$ and $y$, that:

$$\begin{split}
\mathsf P(X=x\mid Y=y) & =\sum_z \mathsf P(X=x\mid Y=y,Z=z)\mathsf P(Z=z) 
\end{split}$$

---

However, it *may be* possible for the two *series* to have the same evaluation although some of the indexed terms are not equal.   $2+3=1+4$ after all.   It would be rarer for this to be so for any $x$ and $y$, but it is still possible.